# How can parent widget gets information from it's children widget in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

I create a parent page contains a list about custom widgets, the list is variable so I can add or decrease the number of these custom widgets immediately.

The custom widgets are contained by

```
  List<FoodContainer> _foods = [];
```

in parent page.

The custom widget looks like:

```
class FoodContainer extends StatefulWidget {
  const FoodContainer({
    Key? key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _FoodContainerState createState() => _FoodContainerState();
}

class _FoodContainerState extends State<FoodContainer> {

  var _result;
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child :TextField(
        onSubmitted: (String s){
          setState(() {
            _result = Func(s);
          });
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Now I want to get the value of _result in every child widget,how can I get them?

I tried to do like this:

```
class FoodContainer extends StatefulWidget {
  const FoodContainer({
    Key? key,
    required this.foodTextControl,
  }) : super(key: key);
  final TextEditingController foodTextControl;
```

The widget.foodTextControl.text can be read in parent page, but the Func(s) is a web request, I don't want to request twice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the _result of all the children (FoodContainers) to the parent (ListView.builder).Then you can use

```
final ValueChanged<String> onChanged;
```

and when the onSubmitted is called you can use this like:

```
widget.onChanged(_result);
```

And on the parent(Listview) you can get the access by:

```
FoodContainer(
onChanged: (val){
   print(val);
   }
```

I hope this will resolve your issue.

Comment: Thank you,I got your idea.So I created a simple custom controller to get the text info.

Comment: You don't need to make custom controller in case you are not making anything complex as there is already ValueChanged<T> available.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for Aswanath C K,I created a simple custom controller to get the child widget info.

```
class TestController extends ValueNotifier<String>{
  TestController({ String? text }) : super(text == null ? "None" : text);

  TestController.fromValue(String? value)
  :assert(
      value == null,'Now:${value}'
    ),
    super(value ?? "None");

  String get text => value;

  set text(String newText) {
    value = newText;
  }

  @override
  set value(String newValue) {
    super.value = newValue;
  }
}
```

When the _result changes,make

```
widget.testController.text = _result;
```

Now it's finished.